# SQL Question on CI Active Record Class Usage

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, php-5.3

I am using CodeIgniter Active Record Class to generat tables, my code snippet below.

I try to generated TWO tables from on DateBase table;
and the two HTML tables named Table_2010 and Table_2011.

```
/////////////////// YEAR 2010 ////////////////
// It works quite well to generate 2010 result table.

$this->db->select('year, distance, gender, rank, name, chiptime, racenumber');

                $this->db->order_by("year", "desc");

                $this->db->order_by("distance, gender, rank", "asc");

                $topNum = 5;
                $year = 2010;                   
                $array = array('rank <=' => $topNum, 'year' => $year);
                $this->db->where($array); 


                $this->load->model('eventmain_model');

                $data['results_2010'] = $this->eventmain_model->get_result_top5($city);

                $tmpl =  $this->common_model->html_table_config(); 

                $this->load->library('table');

                $this->table->set_template($tmpl);

                $this->table->set_heading(array('Year', 'Dis', 'gender','Rank', 'Name', 'ChipTime', 'RaceNo'));



/////////////////// YEAR 2011 ////////////////
// I need query several different fields from the same data base table.
// such as I query 'lap', otherwise 'chiptime'
// It doesn't work well, since it always included 2010 and 2011 data to my 2nd 2011 new table. 
// I want to remove 2010 rows from the 2011 table. How can I fix this?
// Is ther an method to new the db select object and generate my 2011 table?      
//Thanks.                   
                // load database class

                $this->db->select('year, distance, gender, rank, name, lap, racenumber');

                $this->db->order_by("year", "desc");

                $this->db->order_by("distance, gender, rank", "asc");

                $topNum = 5;
                $year = 2011;
                $this->db->where('rank <=', $topNum);
                $this->db->where('year', $year);



                $this->load->model('eventmain_model');

                $data['results_2011'] = $this->eventmain_model->get_result_top5($city);

                $tmpl =  $this->common_model->html_table_config(); 

                $this->load->library('table');

                $this->table->set_template($tmpl);

                $this->table->set_heading(array('Year', 'Dis', 'gender','Rank', 'Name', 'Lap', 'RaceNo'));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: where are you actually executing the query in either case? I don't see a get() so technically it appears that you've built a massive query without ever calling it.

Comment: There is another model file (`get_result_top5()`) to execute the query action. It work quite well. I posted the `$this->db->select();` and `$this->db->where();` part ONLY. I assumed that this part of code need be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I'm as puzzled as you; I don't see how you could get 2011 AND 2010 data when you've limited the year to 2011 in that second query.

Comment: I also very strange at this point. Actually I already limited to year 2011 in my source code. I assumed that the $this->db->where(); doesn't be initialized again when I tried to generate my table_2011. It stored 2010 information in the object. Is is possilbe? How can I initial Active Record Class before another query in the same Model file? thanks.

Comment: I usually have all of my database interaction in the model and don't rely on another object to complete the Active Record query. The only advice I have is to move everything into one place just to see what happens. Your `$this->eventmain_model->get_result_top5()` may not be wrong, but I'd test to be sure that it's not causing problems.

Comment: I modified a little in my original post. `// I need query several different fields from the same data base table.
    // such as I query 'lap', otherwise 'chiptime'` That's why the `get_result_top5()` is common function used a lot. I want to decide what filds used in different HTML table by the Active Recrod Class role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from CI official forum.

```
$this->table->clear();
```

And I fixed the issue by add the code to my View Page. Thanks.

```
echo 'Table_2010<br>';

$this->table->set_heading(array('Year', 'Dis', 'gender','Rank', 'Name', 'ChipTime', 'RaceNo')); 

echo $this->table->generate($results_2010);
$this->table->clear();

echo '<br>';
echo 'Table_2011<br>';
$this->table->set_heading(array('Year', 'Dis', 'gender','Rank', 'Name', 'Lap', 'RaceNo'));
echo $this->table->generate($results_2011);
```